# Cannot inject EntityManagerInterface to use doctrine inside a service on symfony3.4

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4

I added the `EntityManagerInterface` to use doctrine inside the service

```php
namespace AppBundle\Service;

class UploadFileService
{

    private $upload_directory;

    private $is_api;
    private $em;

    public function __construct($upload_directory, EntityManagerInterface $em,$isApi = false )
    {
        $this->upload_directory = $upload_directory;
        $this->is_api = $isApi;
        $this->em = $em;
    }
}
```

and its calles this way

```
$uploadService = new UploadFileService($this->getParameter('upload_directory'));
```

but I get this error

```
Type error: Too few arguments to function AppBundle\Service\UploadFileService::__construct(), 1 passed in /var/www/project/src/AppBundle/Controller/ManageController.php on line 516 and at least 2 expected
```

Autowiring is activated and I checked some answers here and I applied the solution but it doesn't work

Comment: When you use `new UploadFileService`, you don't use the DI container. You need to fetch the `UploadFileService` from the container instead

Comment: use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface ; // ??

Comment: I delete use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface , for space , but its included on he code

Comment: Ok as Nico Haase said when use new UploadFileService, you don't use the DI container.